# PHP login and session establishment

Tags: php, authentication

I have a problem, I searched around a bit but could not find anything that would help me in my particular case.

I come to the point, I created a small function to log log (), inside of course step the variables $ username and $ password, everything works.

The problem is that last night I made a small change, inserting a string of code after the passage of SESSIONS, who was setcookie etc etc because I believed that in doing so the user's connection to last for a long time (I'm no expert).

This morning, the session was timed course, it makes a new login but the data are not passed. (So the User Account box is not refreshed with your username etc.).

I'll post some code:

```
class User {

    private $db;
    private $username;
    private $password;

    /**
     * Construct
     * @param type $pdo
     */
    function __construct($pdo){
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    public function login($username, $password){   
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND status = :status LIMIT 1");
        $this->db->bind(':username', $username);
        $this->db->bind(':status', 1);
        $row = $this->db->single();
        $count = $this->db->rowCount();
            if ($count > 0) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION['session'] = [
                        'id' => $row['id'],
                        'username' => $row['username'],
                        'email' => $row['email'],
                        ];  
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }


    public function isLoggedIn() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['session'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I do not understand what happened, I hope that I explained to the fullest, I apologize for my bad English.

Also another question, is it safe enough to protect the pages?
Some users told me to register the token, but do not know how to do.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: No, im use PDO with this class for the query: http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing

> ","

after 'email' => $row['email'],

And yes, If not started your session, use

```
<?php session_start() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Get PHP Session Variable Values**
>
> session variables are not passed individually to each new page,
>   instead they are retrieved from the session we open at the beginning
>   of each page (session_start())

Straight from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp. In your case you have to start your `session`. You can start your session by using `session_start();`. But remember to do it once at the beginning of your script.

Comment: All it has done, as he said the script was working properly these days.

Comment: @MarcoBonanno you can debug step by step first check if `if (password_verify($password, $row['password']))` this condition is true as you are saying everything is ok

Comment: I saw that the session is successfully passed if redirection log in to the same page, while the session does not pass any given if after making the login redirects the page to any other page, account.php / index.php etc etc ... I do not understand why!